# Downloading file from FileField in Django with a HTTP link in a HTML file

Tags: python, django

I create a link that when a user press it, it will download a pdf file from the media folder in Django to the users machine.

I tried different methods but all were wrong for me. It tells me that the file can not be found, or the code is running but the file is corrupted.

My Html link:

```
<td>  <a href="/download/">Download</a></td>
```

My url pattern links into a view:

```
url(r'^download/$', views.DownloadPdf),
```

My FileField is like this:

```
upload_pdf = models.FileField()
```

Following snippet code is the view that downloads a corrupted pdf:

```
def DownloadPdf(request):

filename = '/home/USER/PycharmProjects/MyProject/media/Invoice_Template.pdf'
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
fileformat = "pdf"
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;
filename=thisismypdf'.format(fileformat)
return response
```

So, what I have to do to make it working ?

Comment: You should serve your `media` folder with you webserver. In development the development server will do this task. Please read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/ for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'Invoice_Template.pdf'), 'rb') as fh:
    response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/pdf")
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=invoice.pdf'
    return response
```

Comment: This reads the whole thing into memory, it's better to use a FileResponse or let the webserver handle sending it.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich yes, you're right, but I think Vaios Lk must understand simple things at first.

Answer (score 1):

@Sergey Gornostaev 's code just work perfect, but i post below my code because it is a aproach in a differect way.

I correct a little bit my code:

```
def DownloadPdf(request):
    path_to_file = '/home/USER/PycharmProjects/MyProject/media /Invoice_Template.pdf'
    f = open(path_to_file, 'r')
    myfile = File(f)
    response = HttpResponse(myfile, content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename'
    return response
```

But only in pdf file ( works with txt files ) gives me that error:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10

Comment: Because you open the file as text but pdf is binary. Change 'r' to 'rb' in `open`.

Comment: Works that too! help me a lot to understand this all. thnx man.