# Allow users to download files directly django

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload

In the TrainerProfileModel I have file field called cv. I want to allow users to download the file directly when clicking on the link. Could you provide any ways to implement this?

models.py:

```
class TrainerProfile(models.Model):
 user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
 null=True, related_name='trainer_profile')
 profile_picture = models.ImageField(blank=True)
 phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone 
 number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits 
 allowed.")
 mobile_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], 
 max_length=17, blank=True)
 location = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
 gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES,max_length=150, 
 blank=True)
 cv = models.FileField(blank=True)
 approval=models.BooleanField(default=False)

 def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

In my template:

```
<li class="list-group-item">
  <b>Download CV</b>
  <a class="pull-right">{{ trainer.cv }}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Yes, use the `href` attribute of the `a` tag with a value of `{{ trainer.cv.url }}`.

Comment: `<a href="{{ trainer.cv.url }}" class="pull-right" download>{{ trainer.cv }}</a>`.

Comment: Most likely it will not work for images, pdf and some video formats. For that you need to create a custom url for downloading files and add proper headers to urls. If not working see this question for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246661/downloading-the-fileswhich-are-uploaded-from-media-folder-in-django-1-4-3

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments use `trainer.cv.url` instead but also there is other approach for this too, take a look at it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40524615/6183805).

GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

We need to till django about our media images so we import the settings in urls.py  by `from django.conf import settings`  and by this code `if settings.DEBUG: urlpatterns += urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`
we till django about our media images ,
**DONOT forget to add Media root and Media URL** by `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` and finally we we add image.**url** in src attribute of image in our html page it will display the image.